# call printf() editing the executable

Tags: string, newline, printf, format-string, hardcode

I'm trying to "crack" a console program, forcing it to display something. The problem is I can't print a newline (`\r\n`).
With a disassebler I found the place and edited the binary:

```
push 4ad0eb46                      ; the string (let's pretend "Hi guys")
push 4ad0eb80                      ; and the format ("%s")
call near ds:[<&msvcrt.printf>]    ; call printf
jmp 4ad0eb4f                       ; skip data

; now here I coded the strings

mov ds:[4ad289ec],eax              ; and here the program resumes
```

As I said, I can't print a newline. I tried encode `"\r\n"` in the format string (so it becomes `"%s\r\n"`, as I would do in C) and get printed `"Hi guys\r\n"`, and encode it in the
string itself (making it `"Hi guys\x13\x10"`) and get `"Hi guys"` and two strange characters, probably the ASCII representation of 0x13 and 0x10.

Comment: What exactly were the "strange characters" you got? What seems strange to you might be useful information to somebody else.

Comment: A sort of '!!' and a triangle, similar to '|>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt, with embedding the characters directly into the string, was the right approach. However, you've used the wrong character numbers. The numbers for return/linefeed in ASCII are 13 and 10 (decimal), which is 0x0d and 0x0a (hex). You've used 0x13 and 0x10, which are different characters.

See the table at [Code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) for the character numbers. The characters 19 and 16 (decimal) are indeed a right pointing triangle and a double exclamation mark.

Answer (score 1):

A newline (in Windows) is `\r\n`.